# Bootstrap 4 horizontal scroll with card-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 , Angular and SCSS

My following card group is like :

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="list">
            <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card" ng-repeat="">
                   data components are here
                </div>
            </div>
      </ul>   
</div>
```

I did not manage to create a scrollbar, a horizontal one  instead of the responsive behavior of card group.

I tried to add `overflow-y:scroll`, but it is not working for horizontal.

Comment: For horizontal scroll, use [overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x), not `overflow-y`. It does not work either because `card` is responsive. You need to avoid it to make it work.

Comment: How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add `overflow-x` for horizontal scroll, 
then you should have  a `max-width` that after it the scroll functionality appear and because it's text you should `white-space` no wrap to be in one line if it's no long text.

```css
.card {
overflow-x: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
max-width: 150px;
padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
      <div class="list">
            <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card" ng-repeat="">
                   data components are here
                </div>
            </div>
      </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: thanks . How can I make margin between the scrollbar and the do . And how can I change the height on hover

Comment: @Guz, you just add padding, I have update the answer with the padding